# Mongoose : Nodejs Unable to delete document with document id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am unable to delete Mongoose Collection document using the below code

```
                    Products.findByIdAndRemove(query.productId,function(err,result){
                        if(err){
                           console.log('Error ',err.message);
                           res.status(400).json({success:false,message:err.message});
                        }
                        console.log('the document is deleted',JSON.stringify(result));
                        return res.status(200).json({success:true});    
                
                    });
```

There are no errors in the Error console.log and the document is still present in the Collection, please assist.

Comment: If there are no errors, then it must mean the query is successful. Is 'the document is deleted' printed? What appears on the console? Did you try to simply log `err` instead of `err.message`?

Comment: 'the document is deleted' is printed with null value for JSON.string....

Comment: Did you make sure `query.productId` is a valid objectId/string? What does `console.log(err, result);` if you put it in the first line of your callback?

Answer (score 0):

what is the type of _id for this document, try adding _id manually.